# Error in COUNTIFS function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I want to count how many vehicles are delayed more than 4 min on a given day according to a given departure (let's assume from 00:00 to 05:00).

This is a sample of the data:

```
A B C D
1 Line Day Departure Delayed (sec)
2 11    Weekday 02:30:00    120
3 11    Weekday 03:40:00    500
4 22    Weekday 01:45:00    10
5 44    Weekday 06:44:00    1000
6 55    Weekday 04:35:00    145
7 111   Saturday    14:40:00    450
8 111   Saturday    04:20:00    300
9 111   Saturday    20:20:00    220
10 111  Saturday    07:00:00    125
11 333  Sunday  09:15:00    700
```

I used a "TÆL.HVISER" function (Danish) or COUNT.IFS function to count the vehicles:

```
=TÆL.HVISER(A2:A11;"11";B2:B11;"Weekday";C2:C11;00:00:00>C2:C11>05:00:00;D2:D11;">240")
```

But it is not working. When I break this restriction into four restrictions, the individual restrictions are working but when I combine them it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've laid out your data according to how I read your sample formula.

[image: Time Delays]

The EN-US formula in G4 is,

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, G$3, $B$2:$B$11, $F4, $C$2:$C$11, ">="&TIME(0, 0, 0), $C$2:$C$11, "<="&TIME(5, 0, 0), $D$2:$D$11, ">="&240)
```

Fill both right and down. I've use the TIME function so that a) real times could be referenced and b) it makes it easier to set to new values.

[TÆL.HVISER, funktionen](https://support.office.com/da-dk/article/T%C3%86L-HVISER-funktionen-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842)

[Funktionen TID](https://support.office.com/da-dk/article/Funktionen-TID-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457)

Answer (score 2):

It is the part

```
00:00:00>C2:C11>05:00:00
```

if you change it to two criteria like this

```
C2:C11;">00:00:00";C2:C11;"<05:00:00"
```

it will work. Here is the full formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A11;"11";B2:B11;"Weekday";C2:C11;">00:00:00";C2:C11;"<05:00:00";D2:D11;">240")
```